# Easily call an Rest api with RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I have an RestApi and i want to use it with my c# mvc client.

I need to send some packet represent by a c# model.

I try RestSharp with the code:

```
//model = UserModel
var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
var request = new RestRequest("/user/register", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("user", model);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");        
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

In response.StatusCode i have BadRequest    System.Net.HttpStatusCode

How can i debug my request ? I try to see the request with wireshark but i don't see any json packet.

EDIT:

When i use AddJsonBody instead of AddParameter it work but my json packet isn't formatted as expect.

I want

```
 {
   "user":
       {"Username": "Test", 
        "Password": "password"
       }
 }
```

with AddJsonBody i have:

```
 {
       {
        "Username": "Test", 
        "Password": "password"
       }
 }
```

How can i give a "name" in the json packet with RestSharp ?

Comment: You can first check the API is working fine or not, to test that you can check it with `chrome` plugin `postman`, when you can sent POST request and see the response.

Comment: With PostMan it work

Comment: From `postman` did you pass header in request? Can you please check by removing header?

Comment: When i remove header in PostMan the api return Bad Request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
request.AddJsonBody(new { user = model });
```

This creates an anonymous type, with the property "user", containing your model. The json serializer should then generate the expected string.